# Why are we checking if temp == null?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

This code is for implementation of linked list.

```
node *single_llist::create_node(int value)
{
    struct node *temp, *s;
    temp = new(struct node); 
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Memory not allocated "<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->info = value;
        temp->next = NULL; 
        return temp;
    }
}
```

1. Here, why are we checking if temp == NULL. I can't think of any case where this can happen
2. Also to exit from if, why are we returning 0 since the return type is node?

Comment: Please post the text of the code you are asking about, as opposed to a link to an image of same code.

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: You don't know how to type text into your question?

Comment: Now is it ok or should I modify

Comment: By default, `new` throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception on allocation failure. There is no reason to check the returned pointer for null unless you use the `nothrow` version of `new`, or overload `new` with a custom implementation, or install a custom `new` failure handler that doesn't throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As the message clearly says, this is in case the request to allocate memory fails.  (Exactly *how* this might happen is irrelevant; it is possible, so the code should handle it.)
2. The author is assuming that `NULL==0`, which is often true, but not necessarily so, and (as we both seem to think) is a bad assumption to make.

Comment: Any scenario where memory allocation can fail?

Comment: So it's better to return null?

Comment: "...it is a bad assumption to make."

Comment: Re: returning `0` or `NULL` - you should return `nullptr`

Comment: _"So it's better to return null?"_ -- no, it's better to leave out the complete `if` block. This is C code, not C++, and it is extremely bad code, too. If `new` fails, it does not return `nullptr`, ever (unless you compile with exceptions turned off, or explicitly call the `nothrow` version). So assume allocation _does fail_, what are you going to do? Seriously, what are you going to do if the program has run out of memory? Besides, returning `nullptr` will, for correctness, require another check in every function calling this function... Altogether, this is very bad. Just let it throw.